# Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a New MVC4 Application and by default Newton JSON added to the Package.

I read that it is useful for serializing and deserializing  JSON. Is this all it does ?

By default we can send JSON in MVC using JSONResult. and using Stringify in JQuery i can receive as a class in C#.

I know there should be some reason why they added Newton JSON.

As i am new to MVC and starting off new project want to know some insight of which serialize/deserialize to go for ?

Thanks

Comment: It's about performance and flexibility. For performance, see http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2012/01/23/json-net-4-0-release-6-serialization-performance.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They added Newtonsoft so that your WebAPI controller can magically serialize your returned object. In MVC 3 we used to return our object like so:

```
public ActionResult GetPerson(int id)
{
    var person = _personRepo.Get(id);
    return Json(person);
}
```

In a **Web API** project you can return person and it will be serialized for you:

```
public Person GetPerson(int id)
{
    var person = _personRepo.Get(id);
    return person
}
```

Comment: So this adds functionality if i use API else i can go with other options ?

Comment: If you are doing an MVC project then you can still use what you know in MVC 3 (e.g. `return Json(the_object)`). If it's an API then no need to serialize on your own.

Comment: A while ago now but I had the same question but came to a different conclusion. Newtonsoft.json is included in a default MVC because WebGrease depends on it, not because WebApi might need it.

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonResult and return `Json(yourObject)` on a post operation, or `Json(yourObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` if you're doing a GET operation.

If you want to deserialize Json with the Newton Json.NET, check out http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek4DeserializingJSONWithJsonNET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your project was just an MVC project with no WebApi, then `Newtonsoft.Json` was not added for returning `JsonResults` as the `JsonResult` returned by MVC uses the `JavaScriptSerializer` as below:

```
 public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }
            if (JsonRequestBehavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet &&
                String.Equals(context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.JsonRequest_GetNotAllowed);
            }

            HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
            {
                response.ContentType = ContentType;
            }
            else
            {
                response.ContentType = "application/json";
            }
            if (ContentEncoding != null)
            {
                response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
            }
            if (Data != null)
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                if (MaxJsonLength.HasValue)
                {
                    serializer.MaxJsonLength = MaxJsonLength.Value;
                }
                if (RecursionLimit.HasValue)
                {
                    serializer.RecursionLimit = RecursionLimit.Value;
                }
                response.Write(serializer.Serialize(Data));
            }
        }
```

In this case it was added because `WebGrease` has a dependency on it. And the bundling and minification services provided by MVC in `System.Web.Optimization` have a dependency on `WebGrease`.

So a default MVC app with no WebApi will have `Newtonsoft.Json` installed for bundling and minification services not WebApi.

To be clear the `JsonResult` returned by WebApi in `System.Web.Http` does use `Newtonsoft.Json` for it's serialization as below:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace System.Web.Http.Results
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Represents an action result that returns an <see cref="F:System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK"/> response with JSON data.
  /// </summary>
  /// <typeparam name="T">The type of content in the entity body.</typeparam>
  public class JsonResult<T> : IHttpActionResult
```

But `Newtonsoft.Json` is not included in a non WebApi, default MVC project just in case you might decide to use some WebApi, it's there because, as above, `WebGrease` needs it. Not sure what they're doing in vNext, probably `Newtonsoft.Json`.